# Don't keep current Page in stack when Navigate in Windows store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm learning Windows 8 development, at current, I've working with Navigation function. I have a Home page, a TrackList page, a Add Playlist page...

I want navigation between page like this:
1. Home page
2. Go to TrackList page
3. Go to Add Playlist page
4. After created playlist, I want auto navigate to the Tracklist and remove the Add Playlist page in current navigation history.

I use the "Frame.SetNavigationState" method to navigate for this case (I read from internet), when playlist was created, I get the current NavigationState and this is the result:

> 1,4,3,31,Hello.View.HubPageHomeH,0,0,33,Hello.View.HubPagePlayer,0,0,40,Hello.View.LibraryTrackList,0,0,42,Hello.View.LibraryAddPlaylist,0,0

I'm not sure what exactly that mean, is there any document talk about above string? How to remove the  Add Playlist page in current navigation history?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From add playlist page use this.Frame.GoBack();. You will be navigated back to Tracklist page and add playlist page will be removed from navigation stack.

Comment: This is a solution but not in other case, this is just a sample. I mean I want to use the SetNavigationState to manage Navigation.